# Magento 2.3.x Product Description showing at short below image place

Tags: product, magento2.3, frontend

so how i can move the product description  container to below image place?.

so i need modify the file `catalog_category_view.xml` and another file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First override the `catalog_category_view.xml` in your theme.

> app/code/design/frontedn/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

After the add this code in the end of file before the `</body>` tag. so your code will be something like :

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="product.info.description" destination="product.info.main" after="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Don't forget to clear cache.

**Hope it will help.**

Comment: Thx, this work for me!.

Answer (score 1):

**You can move the description by adding the below to `catalog_product_view.xml`**

```
<move element="product.info.description" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.addto"/>
```

**destination and before value change as per your requirement..**